# Why OutputDebugString is empty

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015

I create a Win32 app and I have a logIn form, but I can't get a Edit Window value. I did it like this, but get nothing. Where is my mistake?

```
#define passwordWindowId 2

HWND passwordWindowHandle = CreateWindow(TEXT("EDIT"), TEXT(""), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 10, 80, 150, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)passwordWindowId, NULL, NULL);
int len = GetWindowTextLength(GetDlgItem(passwordWindowHandle, passwordEditId));
LPWSTR passwordWindowValue;

GetWindowText(passwordWindowHandle, passwordWindowValue, len + 1);
OutputDebugString(passwordWindowValue);
```

But if I do `OutputDebugString(L"test");` I see `test` in output tab.

Comment: `passwordWindowValue` is uninitialized pointer, it can't receive anything. Also your edit box is blank (second parameter in CreateWindow is the text). So GetWindowText gets empty string. It all works out.

Comment: You are going to have to learn to check for errors. Read the documentation for the functions you call. You don't check for errors at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lots of errors in your code, some subtle and others fatal.

```
#define passwordWindowId 2
```

Some of the low control IDs are used by the dialog manager, and should not be overloaded with user-defined controls. A common convention is to start assigning numbers starting at 100 (see [Why do dialog editors start assigning control IDs with 100?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041214-00/?p=37013)).

Another common convention is to use all uppercase names for preprocessor symbols.

```
HWND passwordWindowHandle = CreateWindow(TEXT("EDIT"), TEXT(""), ...
```

This is creating an **empty** edit control (see the second parameter of [CreateWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679.aspx)). This is not a bug in itself, but you cannot assume that the control contains any text.

Again, not a bug, but using the generic text mappings is generally not helpful. Use the Unicode versions of the APIs together with wide character strings and string literals: `HWND passwordWindowHandle = CreateWindowW(L"EDIT", L"", ...`.

```
LPWSTR passwordWindowValue;
```

`LPWSTR` is a typedef for `wchar_t*`, so the above defines a pointer without initializing it. Not a bug in itself, but when you start using that pointer you run into undefined behavior. You need to allocate storage for the following call to `GetWindowText`, either by creating a local array of fixed size, if you know the maximum size ahead of time, or use a dynamically sized container (e.g. `std::vector<wchar_t> buffer(len + 1);`).

```
GetWindowText(passwordWindowHandle, passwordWindowValue, len + 1);
```

This is where things break: You are requesting an API call to write to unallocated memory, pointed to by an uninitialized pointer. As pointed out above, you need to allocate memory before calling `GetWindowText`. Besides, you are calling the generic text mapping, but passing explicit wide character string types. Use `GetWindowTextW` instead.

```
OutputDebugString(passwordWindowValue);
```

The argument is still an uninitialized pointer. Even if it weren't, the memory pointed to would be an empty string, since the control text is empty. Again, you are calling a generic text mapping, while passing an explicit wide character string. Use `OutputDebugStringW` instead.

Plus, you aren't checking for errors at all. All Windows API calls you are using can fail, and you need to check for failure. See the documentation on how to check for errors for each API call.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Updated!!

```
 LPWSTR passwordWindowValue;
 GetWindowText(passwordWindowHandle, passwordWindowValue, len + 1);
```

This should be

```
 LPWSTR passwordWindowValue = new wchar_t[len + 1];
 GetWindowText(passwordWindowHandle, passwordWindowValue, len + 1);
```

You are passing an uninitalised pointer to GetWindowText

And delete [] passwordWindowValue after you are done.

Comment: I have 2 errors now: `int len -- expression must have constant value` and `WSTR is undefined`. Are you mean `wstring`? I can't find with header has `WSTR`

Comment: Use wchar_t instead of WSTR (which I think @user93353 just made up :)

Comment: Also, c++ doesn't support dynamic length arrays, that's a C feature.

Comment: Hi @JonathanPotter, thank you! But `GetWindowText` and `OutputDebugString` doesn't work with `wchar_t`, right? `int GetWindowTextW(HWND,LPWSTR,int)`.

Comment: The `TCHAR` data type is defined to match the default string type.  So if `GetWindowText` is defined as `GetWindowTextA`, `TCHAR` is `char`.  If `GetWindowText` is `GetWindowTextW`, `TCHAR` is `wchar_t`.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles https://www.dropbox.com/s/dhkfp2m6b16matd/Screenshot%202016-03-20%2013.55.05.png?dl=0 and `GetWindowText` defined as `GetWindowTextW `.

Comment: @rel1x You still need to make an array of `TCHAR`s to hold more than one character.  Something like `TCHAR passwordWindowValue[1024]  = {0};` followed by `GetWindowText(passwordWindowHandle, passwordWindowValue, sizeof(passwordWindowValue)/sizeof(TCHAR));`